# Python csv DictReader reading a column in exception safe manner

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a CSV and I want to retrieve `None` if certain `column` of header of csv is missing.
For example I have a csv with

> A C
> 1 2

```
    with open (input_file,'r') as f:
        csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        count = 0
        for obj in csv_dict_reader:

            str_A= obj["A"]
            str_B= obj["B"]
            str_C= obj["C"]
```

My expectation is if column `B` does not exist in CSV `str_B` should be `None` and then next line should be executed.

Right t now I am getting exception

> KeyError: 'B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=' ', index_col=None)

if 'B' not in df.columns:
  df['B'] = np.NaN
```

### EDIT

If there are 100s of columns missing:

```
all_columns_list = [.....] # list of all potential columns

for col in all_columns_list:
  if col not in df.columns:
    df[col] = np.NaN
```

Comment: 1)If I use above method - then for every column , I have to put this if check which is cumbersome if my csv has 100s of columns

Comment: You have to do that one way or the other. You can setup that check in a loop ideally